# How to show NULL instead of 0 when using sum aggregate / pivoting

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

Consider this 24-hour summary. The problem is that I'm getting 0s returned for hours where values haven't been inserted yet. I believe this is due to the **`SUM()`** function call.

```
SELECT
    section,
    [21], [22], [23], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8],
    [21] + [22] + [23] + [0] + [1] + [2] + [3] + [4] + [5] + [6] + [7] + [8] as s1_total
    -- shift 2 fields are ommitted for brievity
FROM (
    SELECT 
        section,
        -- hours from 21:00 (1st shift) to 20:00 (2nd shift)
        SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '21:00:00' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [21],
        SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '22:00:00' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [22],
        SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '23:00:00' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [23],
        SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '00:00:00' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [0],
        SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '01:00:00' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [1],
        SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '02:00:00' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [2],           
        -- ... similar cases are omitted for brieviety
        SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '20:00:00' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [20]
    FROM (
        SELECT prTime, prDate, section01 AS Amount, 'section 1' as [Section] FROM SectionsHourlyValues
        UNION
        SELECT prTime, prDate, section02 AS Amount, 'section 2' as [Section] FROM SectionsHourlyValues
        UNION
        SELECT prTime, prDate, section03 AS Amount, 'section 3' as [Section] FROM SectionsHourlyValues
    ) AS U
    WHERE 
        (prDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -4, CONVERT(DATETIME2(7), @dt, 104))) and prTime > '20:00:00') or 
        (prDate = CONVERT(DATE, @dt, 104) and prTime <= '20:00:00')
    GROUP BY section
) t;
```

For example, running the query

```
DECLARE @dt varchar(10) = 'certain_date';
SELECT * from [dbo].[SectionsHourlyValues] WHERE
    (prDate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -4, CONVERT(DATETIME2(7), @dt, 104))) and prTime > '20:00:00') or 
    (prDate = CONVERT(DATE, @dt, 104) and prTime <= '20:00:00');
```

wouldn't return us the data for say **09:00:00** / **section1** whereas the summary would show us **0**.

Then I want to show **`NULL`** (for not yet inserted records) instead of **`0`**. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing the 0 with `NULL` in your conditional aggregation ?

```
SUM(CASE WHEN etc... ELSE NULL END)
```

Comment: I don't know what about sql-server, but in oracle when you sum nulls value it doesn't sum right.

Comment: @sagi , oh i see .. you can try .. but if you want to make sure , i've seen the answer above using `NULLIF` or you can simply remove the `ELSE` , he's correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use NULLIF

ex

```
NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '21:00:00' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END),0)
```

or simply do not use ELSE

```
SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '21:00:00' THEN Amount END)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `0` values not due to the [SUM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) function for values not yet inserted (that would be NULL and would ignored by the SUM function), but because the ELSE of your CASE statement returns 0:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '21:00:00' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [21]
```

To solve your problem, you can use [NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) that is rather similar to [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
NULLIF(MyExpressionThatCouldReturn0, 0)
```

That in your case would be:

```
NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '01:00:00' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END),0)
```

Otherwise, as said before, do not use ELSE in the CASE statement, used as parameter of your SUM:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN prTime = '21:00:00' THEN Amount END)
```